# Desfazer EditingControlShowing

Tags: c#

Tenho um DataGrid em que uma determinada coluna só podem ser inseridos números, sendo assim usei o "EditingControlShowing" para avaliar a entrada do usuário nessa coluna e só permitir números.

```
string columnName = dataGridView_CP.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name;
IEnumerable<string> itemsNumero = new List<string> { "C_Altura" };
IEnumerable<string> itemsString = new List<string> { "Column_Id", "Column_Lote", "Column_Data" };

DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl tb = (DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl)e.Contro;

if (itemsNumero.Contains(columnName))
{
     tb.KeyPress -= new KeyPressEventHandler(dataGridViewTextBox_KeyPress);
     tb.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(dataGridViewTextBox_KeyPress);
     tb.TextChanged -= new EventHandler(dataGridViewTextBox_TextChanged);
     tb.TextChanged += new EventHandler(dataGridViewTextBox_TextChanged);
}

if (itemsString.Contains(columnName))
{
     tb.KeyPress -= new KeyPressEventHandler(dataGridViewTextBox_KeyPress);
     tb.TextChanged -= new EventHandler(dataGridViewTextBox_TextChanged);
}
```

Acontece que se o usuário entra para digitar algo nessa coluna a propriedade funciona, mas quando ele clica em outra célula para digitar um dado, e verificação de digitar apenas números continua ativa. 
Existe uma forma de desativar essa entrada antes de entrar em outra célula?

O problema parece estar no "TextChanged" que executa antes de a próxima célula entrar no "EditingControlShowing" dela.

Answer (score 1):

O problema ocorre é porque você seta o evento para todas as colunas, sendo que você deve definir o evento apenas nas colunas que deseja consistir, você pode fazer isso pegando o index da coluna que você deseja consistir, veja esse código que eu já uso em algumas aplicações minhas:

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    // Aqui pega o index da coluna que está selecionada.
    int colIndex = this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;

    // Aqui eu verifico se a coluna que está selecionada é a coluna que vou consistir a entrada de dados.
    if (colIndex == 0)
        e.Control.KeyPress += dataGridView1_KeyPress;
    else
        e.Control.KeyPress -= dataGridView1_KeyPress;
}

private void dataGridView1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    // Aqui eu só permito a informação de números
    e.Handled = !(Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar == 8);
}
```

Comment: Na verdade estou selecionado a coluna. No meu "if" se é coluna de string eu removo os eventos, se é coluna de número eu ativo.
Se eu usar somente o evento "KeyPress" como você demostrou funciona. O problema é que além desse eu utilizo o "TextChanged" que  uso para quando o usuário trouxer um texto através de cont+c, pois mesmo que eu tenha colocado o KeyPress apenas números, se colar um texto ele aceita. O problema é que após usar uma célula com número assim que clico em outra célula antes do EditingControlShowing ser executado o TextChanged é, e se a célula contiver letra, essa é deletada.